# Unable to launch Jboss Developer Studio

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss-developer-studio

When I double click the jbdevstudio.exe I'm getting below error. I suspect this has got to do with the wrong jdk path (default path), in which file i can now give the correct jdk path?

**java was started but returned exit code = 13
C:\Program Files\Common files\oracle\java\javapath\javaw.exe**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What the JBDS version you are using?
- What JDK version you have installed and executing this jbdevstudio.exe file?
- If you are using JBoss Developer Studio 9.0.0 or later, you have to run the installer using Java 8. Then use the JDK to run JBoss Developer Studio.

Possible root cause for this issue is JBDS pointing to the incorrect JDK version for the underlying architecture.

Comment: I use Jboss dev studio 7.1.1  and jdk 8. In environment variables --> system variables--> I changed the JAVA_HOME path and pointed it to the folder where my jdk 8 is installed (C:\Users\user1\Documents\java\jdk 8\bin ). Also changed the Path variable and added this path (C:\Users\user1\Documents\java\jdk 8\bin, At this point I'm confused if i need to add %JAVA_HOME%\bin  in my path variable? What else would you suggest me to change to make my jboss dev studio launch successfully. I'm newbie, please help me out.

Comment: I read somewhere i need to give this jdk 8 path in "eclipse.ini" file and "standalone.conf" file, Im not sure where exactly to do the change in this file?

Comment: Hi, JBDS 7 is very older version, If you are trying for the first time, try to use latest version instead of older version. Currently JBDS 12.19 is available, you can download the installer jar from Red Hat portal and install it with JDK 8 and then run it.   If you still want to use JBDS 7 then I would suggest try with lower JDK version like JDK 6/7.